# React Native Web View not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to show a simple webview in my react native application.

This is the code I'm trying:

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <WebView
        source={{uri: 'https://logrocket.com/'}}
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

When I run this code I get a single red pixel on the screen. I don't know why I get this and I don't know how to debug it, because I don't see any errors.

I am using the latest version of React Native.

This is what the output of the code looks like on my end:

[image]

Comment: did you add flex:1 on webview  style?

Comment: Yes I tried but still not working

Comment: what about  originWhitelist={['*']} prop ? have you tried?

Comment: Where should I place it in the code ? I don't know about this

Comment: <WebView
          originWhitelist={['*']}
... />

Comment: Just tried and still not working...

Comment: Is my code working when you execute it on yuor computer?

Comment: I put my working code in an answer, you can test it.

Comment: Where did you put your code ?

Comment: you can check it in asnwer

Comment: Are you perhaps trying this on `web`? Because the code you posted is working just fine for me on a physical device. Related issue: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/1501.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... will work

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default function App() {
  return (
      <WebView
        source={{ uri: 'https://logrocket.com/' }}
        style={{ marginTop: 20}}
      />
  );
}
```

Comment: Is this code working on your computer when you execute it ?

Comment: is react-native-webview, showing in your project package.json ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Image} from 'react-native';
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';


const Test= () => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <WebView
          originWhitelist={['*']}
          source={{html: a}}
          style={{width:"100%", height: 300}}
        />
        <View></View>
    </View>
  );
};
export default Test;

const a = `
<body>
</body>
`
```

This is my working code

Comment: Ok this is very very weird because it doesn't work for me ...